# what /bin/sed '/^$/d'| /bin/sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' mean?

Tags: unix, sed, command

Please explain the two 'sed' command in the following line:

```
/bin/cat $TMPFILE |  /bin/sed '/^$/d'| /bin/sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' > $RPTFILE
```

Thanks in advance,
Betty

Answer (score 3):

`sed '/^$/d'` Delete empty lines
`sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'` remove leading spaces and tabs.

`^` start of line  `$` end of line, so `^$` line with just start and end, no data.
`[ \t]*` group of space or tab (`\t`). `*` repeat zero or more times.

Comment: you could add that the 2 could be build in 1 sed (avoiding pipe) with `sed '/^$/d;s/^[ \t]*//'` or still better `'/^$/d;s/p[[:space:]]*//'`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu True, but OP asked for the meaning :)  Updated my post.

Comment: The second is not "remove lines with tab and space only", it is "remove leading spaces and tabs". And `[ \t]` is better written as `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: Thanks NeronLeVelu, Jotne, and Glenn!